# Wheezy to Jessie upgrade / (root partition) minimal requirements in MB?

Tags: boot, partition, upgrade

The Linux Debian kernel is 3.2.0-4-686-pae.

The `/` (root) partition is 62% full. Will the remaining space suffice to install Jessie's kernel & boot stuff?

```
mt42@hostname:~$ df -k
Filesystem                         1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                240972   141168     87363  62% /
```

I am not certain about the magic the Debian does when upgrading the kernel. 
I reckon often old and new versions are kept. 
What will `dpkg` do if there is not enough space for both (240 MB)?

Comment: Are you upgrading just kernel, or whole debian system?

Comment: putting `/var/cache/apt/archives` on a different drive can save a lot of space.

Comment: Actually, the plan was to completely upgrade from wheezy to jessie, but the most critical disk space consideration is that of root partition.

Comment: P.S. The df -k command is showing just root partition, as it is the only critical in terms of available vs. needed size. While ago, there was an issue with too big root or /boot partitions of kernels we used, they could not exceed certain size.

Comment: @mt42 Did you do it in the end? How much space did it use? You could put your results in an answer if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the upgrade and before proceeding, the system will confirm with you the amount of space required. **Jessie** will replace old **Wheezy** files so, the final byte count may be low, however, there is no easy way to advise you on how much space you will need: is highly system dependent. With new *Kernel headers*, Most applications and utilities will be require reinstallation, with some extra space, at least, temporary!

On my upgrade, I finish using ~180Mb of additional space, however, I'm not sure how much space was required during the upgrade to download, expand, install and (possibly) delete required packages.

With just 240MB available, I will not advise the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, because the kernel takes about 100mB give or take when installed, but you can't remove the running kernel until you rebooted (unless you can), so you have to have at least the two installed. But you also need the package, which is around 25-30 mB, and you need the room to extract it prior to installation. But it probably won't be only the kernel, assuming no kernel headers package, there's still going to be other dependencies that also have to be pulled in.

I'm curious how you can get an install down to this size in the first place, I didn't think debian would run with so few packages.

My smallest install, though it has xorg/fluxbox, is an Etch, I think, on a 1 gB ssd, and that one I couldn't upgrade at all due to space limits. That's about 600 mB.

Best course I think is to try:

1. change to wheezy sources.
2. Run apt-get update
3. Do: apt-get install -s [kernel]

-s for simulate. But that won't I believe show you the sizes of packages downloaded.

I'd be curious just in general to see if it's possible, depends on how important the system is.

Oh, apt-get update is also going to pull in about 15, 20mB of update files as well.